# Two way binding not working with contenteditable in directive template

Tags: angularjs, binding, angularjs-directive, contenteditable, angularjs-ng-model

I have created a directive with a template specified. I would like to see whatever i type in the `debug` div below the textbox. But `debug` shows only the initial value and its not getting updated. I think there is some silly mistake that i might be doing. But i am not able to figure it out.

Following is the directive:

```
angular.module('directiveBinding', [])
  .directive('mydirective', function() {
    var my_template = '<div contenteditable="true" ng-model="myobj.text"' + 
        'class="contenteditable col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">{{myobj.text}}</div>' +
        '<div class="debug clearfix"><br>{{myobj.text}}</div>';

    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      console.log('Linker called');
      console.log('scope.myobj.text: ' + scope.myobj.text);
    }

    var controller = function($scope) {
      $scope.myobj = {};
      $scope.myobj.text = 'some value';
      $scope.text = "hello world"

      console.log('$scope.myobj.text: ' + $scope.myobj.text);
    }

    return {
      require: '?ngModel',
      restrict: "E",
      link: linker,
      controller: controller,
      template: my_template,
      scope: {}
      };
  });
```

And i am using it as follows:

```
<mydirective></mydirective>
```

**Edit**

The above code works if i change the template to use `<input>` instead of `contenteditable` div.

```
var my_template = '<input type="text" ng-model="myobj.text"' + 
    'class="contenteditable col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">{{myobj.text}}</input>' +
    '<div class="debug clearfix"><br>{{myobj.text}}</div>';
```

[Here is the plunker for the same.](http://plnkr.co/edit/8pEb0klulgehwtFfjoAd)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue lies with $scope.text, you should never bind to primitives.

In your html change ng-model="text.something" and also {{text}} to {{text.something}}.